# Hadoop 3.1.1 etc and sbin files

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am trying to setup Hadoop 3.1.1 on Mac.

Any advice which files I need to edit inside etc file and inside libexe/sbin ?

What I have to write inside it

Comment: You shouldn't edit any sbin or bin files, only etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for installing Hadoop 3.1.1 in Mac,

**Option 1:**

1. Prerequisites: Install HomeBrew

   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Check Hadoop is available in Homebrew by `brew info hadoop`. It may show that version 3.1.1 is stable.
3. Install Hadoop by `brew install hadoop`. This will install Hadoop 3.1.1 with all its dependencies.

**Option 2**:

Manually downloading Hadoop 3.1.1 from the Apache website and updating the configs manually.

1. Prerequisites: Install Java
2. Download Hadoop Binary package from Apache Mirror site https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.1/hadoop-3.1.1.tar.gz
3. For Pseudo-Distributed mode, export JAVA_HOME.
4. Update these configs

Edit *etc/hadoop/core-site.xml:*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

5. *Setup passphraseless ssh*
   Now check that you can ssh to the localhost without a passphrase:

   $ ssh localhost
   If you cannot ssh to localhost without a passphrase, execute the following commands:

   $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
     $ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Then,
6. *Format the filesystem:*

```
 $ bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

7. *Start NameNode daemon and DataNode daemon:*

   $ sbin/start-dfs.sh
8. Browse the web interface for the NameNode; by default it is available at:
   **NameNode - http://localhost:9870/**

Comment: Thanks Paul it works for me, but I would suggest to use ./start-all.sh